# flex unrecognized option nounput

Tags: compiler-errors, bison, flex-lexer

when I compile I get the error:
motion.in:7: unrecognized %option:
if i do not have have the option It tells me that unput is defined but not used

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "motion.tab.h"
%}
%option noinput nounput‏
DISTANCE    [0-9]+
%%
u           return U;
d           return D;
l           return L;
r           return R;
n           return N;
{DISTANCE}  {yylval.numval=atoi(yytext); return NUM;}
\n          return END;
```

Comment: What flex version are you using? (`flex --version`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an instance of the Unicode character U+2005 (a thin fixed-width space) after the word `nounput`.

Delete the line and retype it in a text editor, not a word processor.